# Angular ui.router dynamic sidebar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have now tried whole day and i cant figure out how i shall solve this issue.
My goal is to display a sidebar thats get filled with data based on what state it is.

Lets say i am on the **home page** i may like this items:

1. Home item 1
2. Home item 2

And if i am on the **about page** i want this items:

1. About me
2. About my dog

I would like the data to get fetched from a service that returns data to the view based on what state it is.

I have tried to use ui.router's resolve function but i can't get the correct structure in my head to make it work.

Created a plunkr that shows how i mean but without the solution, what are the best practices and preferred ways when creating a dynamic sidebar with Angular and ui.router?

```
myapp.config(function($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: "",
          views: {
            "content": {
              template: "This is the home.content"
            },
            "sidebar": {
              templateUrl: 'sidebar.html',
              controller: 'sidebarCtrl'
            }
          }
        })
        .state('about', {
          url: "/about",
          views: {
            "content": {
              template: "This is the about.content"
            },
            "sidebar": {
              templateUrl: 'sidebar.html',
              controller: 'sidebarCtrl'
            }
          }
        })
    })
```

[Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OLPBe7LgK6VcvjN6hvD0?p=preview)

**Edit**

Can't figure  out what i am doing wrong, no view is shown with this code:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to root
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
        .state('root', {
            url: '',
            'abstract': true,
            views: {
                'sidebar@': {
                    templateUrl: '/App/Main/views/shared/sidebars/sidebar.cshtml',
                    controller: 'app.controllers.views.shared.sidebars.sidebar',
                    resolve: {
                        sidebarData: function (sidebarService) {
                            return sidebarService.getActions();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        })
    .state('root.home', {
        url: "/",
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: '/App/Main/views/home/home.cshtml',
                controller: 'app.controllers.views.home'
            },
            'content@root.home': {
                templateUrl: '/App/Main/views/home/home-content.cshtml',
                controller: 'app.controllers.views.home'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.about', {
        url: "/customers",
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: '/App/Main/views/customers/customers.cshtml',
                controller: 'app.controllers.views.customers'
            },
            'content@root.about': {
                templateUrl: '/App/Main/views/customers/customers-content.cshtml',
                controller: 'app.controllers.views.customers'
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

and here is how my home and customer views look like:

```
<div data-ui-view="sidebar">
    Loading sidebar view.
</div>
<div data-ui-view="content">
    Loading content view.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you could try to implement named and also an abstract view for your sidebar to reuse it among your other routes, also you can use the resolve parameter an return whatever dynamic data you need (from a service, resource, whatever), it could be something like this:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
     myapp.config(function($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider
      .state('root',{
          url: '',
          abstract: true,
          views: {
            'sidebar@': {
              templateUrl: 'sidebar.html',
              controller: 'sidebarCtrl',
              resolve:{
                sidebarData:function(){
                  return  [{
                         state: '/stateHere',
                         text: 'Need'
                         }, {
                        state: '/stateHere',
                        text: 'to'
                        }, {
                        state: '/stateHere',
                        text: 'fill'
                        }, {
                        state: '/stateHere',
                        text: 'this'
                         }, {
                        state: '/stateHere',
                        text: 'with'
                        }, {
                        state: '/stateHere',
                        text: 'dynamic'
                        }, {
                        state: '/stateHere',
                       text: 'data'
                       }];
                }
              }
            }
        })
        .state('root.home', {
          url: "/",
          views: {
            'content@': {
              template: "This is the home.content"
            }
          }
        })
        .state('root.about', {
          url: "/about",
          views: {
            'content@': {
              template: "This is the about.content"
            }
          }
        })
    });

     myapp.controller('sidebarCtrl', ['$scope','sidebarData'
      function($scope,sidebarData) {
            $scope.sidebarData= sidebarData,

      }
    ]);
```

**EDIT:**

check this working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Nqwlkq1vGh5VTBid4sMv?p=preview

Comment: thanks this is perfect, but what should i check in the service to determine witch row that should be returned? I need to implement some state, or id check right ?

Comment: it could be depends on your logic, but if you plan to get the states from the server for example, This article might be helpful to you :) http://alexfeinberg.wordpress.com/2014/03/08/dynamically-populating-angular-ui-router-states-from-a-service/ cheers!

Comment: ty @jack.the.ripper still can't figure out how to solve the basic setup. Updated my post.

Comment: the name your stateprovicer is '' and you are using a named view named contaner in your markup, I'd suggest to change it from '' to 'content@'

Comment: try step by step it should be something like,  views:{
    'content@': {
     templateUrl: 'home.html',
     controller:'HomeController'
    }
   }

Comment: thanks but i dont think that solves the issue, i want to be able to 'insert' the sidebar with the resolved data in my root.home state.

Comment: I get your point, but what I'm trying to say is that you could do it setp by setp once you have the views render correctly then you can add the resolve functionality, anyway the sidebar will be loaded depending on if you have dedined the named view or now in the markup